# React Native Text inside ImageBackground wrapper is not displaying (With Image)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

The text in my imagebackground wrapper is not displayed when I set imageStyle position to relative.

```
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{ position: 'relative', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }} delayPressIn={500} onPressIn={() => this.onPressInMic()} onPressOut={() => this.onPressOutMic()}>
      <ImageBackground imageStyle={{ position: 'relative', backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} source={this.state.micOn ? Images.micOn : Images.micOff} >
        {
          this.state.micOn
            ? (
              <Text style={styles.micText}>PRESS TO{'\n'}STOP</Text>)
            : (
              <Text style={styles.micText}>PRESS TO{'\n'}RECORD</Text>
            )
        }
      </ImageBackground>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

[image]

The text is supposed to be inside the image like
[image]

Comment: It seems your text is hidden below the timer, can you add relevant code to generate  this issue?

Comment: @PritishVaidya Hi please see the added image. The text is supposed to be inside the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `ImageBackground` comes with [`absoluteFill`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0f6762ba50b92a16fa11f10142b4416aace57f5e/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js#L63) style.

By setting `position: 'relative'`, to the `image styles` you're making it **relative to the view container** as defined [**here**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0f6762ba50b92a16fa11f10142b4416aace57f5e/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js#L63). Therefore the children elements will always come below the `ImageBackground`

The workaround would be to remove the `position: 'relative'` in the styles and use parent container `style` object.

as `ImageBackground styles={'//...View container styles'}`